# Unable to access Parallels Plesk Panel account

Tags: dns, web-config, webserver, plesk, internal-server-error

I have come to an issue while logging into the **Parallels Plesk Panel** with the username and password provided by our hosting agent.
It was going fine until I removed a directory through FileZilla application, which was holding the contents of a running live website.

After resetting the directory, I got an error message:

> Internal error: Domain Service Web not exists: domain=example.com,
>
> id=XXXX Domain Service Web not exists: domain=example.com, id=XXXX File
>
> DSWeb.php Line    76 Type    PleskFatalException

Then I found a solution after searching the error. But that was saying about **removing and adding entries from and to `psa database`**. I am using a windows system and no way to access this `psa database`.

Then I found some **server administration service providers** can solve this issue but they are asking tickets and payments. I doubt if they can help or if **they ask me the credentials of the service**. Is that the only and safe solution?

And somewhere else I saw I can use **`dbclient utility` for running SQL query on Windows**. How does that help?

Now I **can't login through the panel**, it shows the error:

> The xxx.xxx.xxx.xx page isn’t working
>
> xxx.xxx.xxx.xx redirected you too many times. Try: Reloading the page
>   Clearing your cookies ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

**I am not able to access mail accounts** and some **domains**(were running good) **show this error message:**

> The service is unavailable.

The one which I removed (directory and files) shows **`Web Server's Default Page`** of Parallels Plesk Panel  when accessing the domain address through web browser.

I don't see any questions like this here in Stack overflow, but there are tags.
Waiting for your suggestion and help me to find the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/ru-RU/online/plesk-linux-advanced-administration-guide/index.htm?fileName=68745.htm

Trouble shouting for:

**Cannot Access Panel**

**Cannot Log In to Panel**

If you get the error message "Access for administrator from address xx.xx.xx.xx is restricted in accordance with IP Access restriction policy currently applied." when trying to access Parallels Plesk Panel, it means that the Panel IP access policy does not allow you to log in from your current IP.

To access Panel from an IP address:
Here is a way of access psa table.

1-Log in to the server via SSH.Using Putty
2-Change the IP access policy in the psa database:

To find the current policy and its restricted and allowed IP addressess,run the following commands.

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow ` psa

mysql> select * from cp_access;

mysql> select * from misc where param='access_policy';
```

**Panel in a Virtuozzo Container: Broken Layout**